# Force a class in Java to call a method

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, interface

I have a class which holds a private member (which itself is an object). I want to access the member in a legitimate way and modify its properties. The way I thought of doing this is to make the class call a method of my class (where I want to access it) with its private member.

For example, I have class `ClassA` which has property `mItem`. I want to get the instance of `mItem` in `ClassB` so that I can call `mItem.update()` at a later point of time (when user updates something on UI). From `ClassB`, I want to call a method of `ClassA` (say, `passItem`) that actually calls some method (say, `obtainItem(Item item)`) of `ClassB` passing `mItem`. However, I want to enforce this, so that `passItem` implementation mandates calling `obtainItem` of `ClassB` with `mItem`.

Any ideas?

Comment: And classA does not have a getter/setter for that property? Mabye that would be the most common way to deal with that. A real-world example would heöp a lot in helping you.

Comment: Why not make an update method in ClassA that delegates to mItem? Why are you breaking encapsulation? If ClassA and ClassB are dependent on each other's internals so much what's the point of having them as different classes?  For the second case does ClassA hold an instance of ClassB? Are they static methods? Again why do they depend so much on the internals of each other? Give a proper example of what you are trying to achieve. Basically tell the problem instead of asking to fix the solution.

Comment: @Jan, @aseem-bansal One can think of `ClassA` as a container for many classes such as `ClassB`, `ClassC`. The instance of `ClassA` holds this instance of `mItem` which the instances of `ClassB`, `ClassC` can update (by calling `mItem.update()` and some other methods). That's why I want the reference to `mItem`.

Comment: A container without getters seems quite useless to me. Unless the container protects the inner values for a reason. Is the container / classA **your** code as well?

Comment: @jaibatrik it would be much easier to understand what you mean, and suggest a solution, if we didn't have to "think about" the classes, but could just see them. Post your code instead of describing it.

Comment: `ClassA` is an `Activity` and `ClassB` and `ClassC` are `Fragment` s (Android). Once the `Activity` opens, it fetches the values from DB and intializes `mItem` (member of `ClassA`). Any action done on `Fragment`s should update the shared `mItem`.

Comment: That still isn't code. You got 3 answers: 1 is forced to make assumptions on your code, and the two others are from the same author, who had to write another answer based on critical information that you posted, later, as a comment. That is a strong indication that your question is a bad one. Edit your question, and post the code. Not just class names. The code.

Comment: Yeah, let me draft it quickly.

Comment: Updated the question, with code. But I wanted it to be a design question. May be my language was not descriptive enough :(

Comment: @jaibatrik If you want it to be a design question - then better describe each class without using programming terminology at all. What is the function of DetailsActivity? What is the function of DetailsFragment? What do they represent in your code? How is mItem tied into this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the source code of `ClassA`, then the usual way to access private members is to selectively add [delegate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) setter and getter methods for the member properties that you are interested in.

If you do not have access to its source code, though, things become a bit more complex. The standard way to do this is to use [Java reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to retrieve a reference to the private member. This, however, violates some of the principles of OOP by having external entities depend on the implementation of `ClassA`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Delegation pattern. I'll give it a try. Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make use of the Command Pattern to implement this. Allowing A and B to pass back and forth commands to process (upon their internally stored member variables) Making the member variable both the reciever/invoker , and class A and B as the 'client', with some set of 'commands' that are being passed back and forth.

---

Below describes using 4 different classes, but combining 2 of them into 1 is fine.

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

**Rationale/Use:**

> Using command objects makes it easier to construct general components
>   that need to delegate, sequence or execute method calls at a time of
>   their choosing without the need to know the class of the method or the
>   method parameters.

**Design:**

> Four terms always associated with the command pattern are **command,
>   receiver, invoker** and **client**. A command object knows about receiver
>   and invokes a method of the receiver. *Values for parameters of the
>   receiver method are stored in the command*. The receiver then does the
>   work. An invoker object knows how to execute a command, and optionally
>   does bookkeeping about the command execution. The invoker does not
>   know anything about a concrete command, it knows only about command
>   interface. Both an invoker object and several command objects are held
>   by a client object. The **client decides which commands to execute at
>   which points**. To execute a command, it passes the command object to
>   the invoker object.

The Client doesn't know the inside workings of either the invoker or of the commands. and that is what is good about it. The client can think of them as 'atomic' events that they can start (by passing the command to the receiver) whenever they want.

So for example if I had a video game, I could have a magic book(receiver), some scrolls (commands), there would be a Hero/Heroine that would be the (client), and the magic imp(invoker) that takes the scroll's contents(the command) and knows how to convert it into 'input'(params) for the book(receiver)

---

The Client doesn't know the details of the Command nor of the receiver. (nor of the invoker). It just has a 'group of commands' that it can assign to receiver methods how it chooses. Without having to know anything about the internal makeup of any of the 3 other classes.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer was when I didn't realize you wanted to work with Activities/Fragments.

There is a set 'best practice' for this when doing that.

you create an interfaceB and interfaceC (could be exact same interface, but could be separate) that your activity implements.

Then after you instantiate your fragment, but before you attach it, you pass `this` to a setter of the Fragment.

The fragment internally would store that as an instance of `instance(B|C)` (depending on which fragment you are in).

This allows you to call (the interface) methods of A from B and C.

(You can also have the activity store references to B and C, and call methods that direction too)

This allows 2-way communication between fragments and the underlying Activity.

---

You would then 'route' communication either through A (viable) or call setters on B and C once both are initialized allowing them to have references of each other (now talking directly between each other)